# The method setJsonHttpRequestInitializer is undefined for the type Drive.Builder Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am creating an application to working with Google Drive on Android.

I've searched in internet for a few examples, but they all are the same. I'm getting the following error:

```
Object Drive.Builder does not have method setJsonHttpRequestInitializer.
```

I have tested with Google drive API V1 and V2 without luck.

Where is the problem?

Source:

```
private Drive getDriveService(String accountName) {

   HttpTransport ht = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();                     
   JacksonFactory jf = new JacksonFactory();          
   Credential credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setAccessToken(accountName);           

        Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(ht, jf, null);
        b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {

            @Override
            public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
                driveRequest.setOauthToken(accountName);
                driveRequest.setKey(API_KEY);
            }
        });
        return b.build();
}
```

Found that setJsonHttpRequestInitializer method is undefined if use google-api-java-client-1.12.0-beta

Downloaded and imported google-api-java-client-1.11.0-beta

But now getting:
Using Client ID for installed applications: Client ID.

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
 {
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
     "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
     "message": "Access Not Configured"
    }
   ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Access Not Configured"
  }
 }
```

Using Simple API Access: API key

```
Exceptioncom.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Here is project sources:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/an6xxy

What is wrong, maybe something with Certificate fingerprint (SHA1)?

Trying calendar-android-sample from google.

Looks like i have problems with register app in google api console.

Where to put client id which i get in sample?

After run sample in debug mode in android, getting "access not configured".

Answer (score 2):

On Android, the best practice is to use Google Play services for OAuth 2.0.  As of version 1.12.0-beta of the library, you should use [GoogleAccountCredential](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.12.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential.html) to accomplish this.

Please use the example I wrote [calendar-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html) as a guide for the best practice for OAuth 2.0 on Android.  Please read the instructions carefully.  Note that you must first register your application in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) for this to work.  Code snippet from the sample:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...
  // Google Accounts
  credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
  SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  credential.setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
  // Calendar client
  client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
      transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("Google-CalendarAndroidSample/1.0")
      .build();
}
```

Comment: Trying create client id for calendar sample, but getting: An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it. Is this temporary on google?

Comment: Found that it happens because package name is to long.

Comment: Trying calendar sample, where to set the client id which i made in google api console?

Comment: @user1826780 Thanks a ton. I was going mad at this and your comment save my day!!

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an older version of the Java library.

Anyway, you can use the instance of the `GoogleCredential` object as `HttpRequestInitializer`, as in the following code:

```
private Drive getDriveService(String token) {
  Credential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);
  Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(
      AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential);
  return b.build();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that helped. But now getting that Access is not configured. I have created API KEY in google api console for Google Drive and wrote it in Manifets, but without luck.  Exceptioncom.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
 {
   "code" : 403,
   "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "usageLimits",
     "message" : "Access Not Configured",
     "reason" : "accessNotConfigured"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Not Configured"
 }

Comment: The Drive API doesn't use the API Key for authorization, instead you need an authorization token as explained at https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/authentication

Comment: Added more info, can someone help?

Comment: Check the new Android quickstart for Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android