# Replacement for setJsonHttpRequestInitializer for Drive.Builder

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using `google-api-services-drive-v2-rev39-java-1.12.0-beta` (Latest during the time writing)

I found that `setJsonHttpRequestInitializer` no longer appear in `Drive.Builder`

```
    final HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
    // authToken is String.
    credential.setAccessToken(authToken);
    // ClientCredentials.KEY is String, generated from https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?api=drive#project:369087808589
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(Utils.getApplicationName())
        .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new GoogleKeyInitializer(ClientCredentials.KEY))
        .build();
```

If I execute the code without calling `setJsonHttpRequestInitializer`, I will get

**Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.**

Is there any way I can pass API key (`ClientCredentials.KEY`) to `Drive.Builder`?

Note : Check already [The method setJsonHttpRequestInitializer is undefined for the type Drive.Builder Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398607/the-method-setjsonhttprequestinitializer-is-undefined-for-the-type-drive-builder) . Doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Android quickstart in the Google Drive SDK documentation for the correct way to build your service and authorize your requests on Android:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: Seems like I missed out step "Requires SHA-1 registered in console". Now, the thing works even without `setJsonHttpRequestInitializer`. Is this something introduced recently?

Comment: This is new flow since the launch of Google Play Services, which I think is at least a few months old